# Не получается сделать картинки справа от текста в блоке footer

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.Logo {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
header{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.header-logo{
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.header-nav{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: large;
    padding: 10px;
}
.line-second {
  border-top: 8px solid #a292b3;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: top;
}
.right {
  width: 34px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 66px 179px 0 0;
  padding: 16px 9px 17px 3px;
  background-color: #82699d;
}
.left {
  width: 34px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 66px 179px 0 0;
  padding: 16px 9px 17px 3px;
  background-color: #82699d;
}
.banner h2{
  width: 297px;
  height: 84px;
  margin: 20px 320px 27px 38px;
  opacity: 0.97;
  text-shadow: 0px 6px 0 rgba(130, 105, 157, 0.75);
  font-family: StRyde;
  font-size: 117px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 0.31;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.97);
}
.banner p{
  width: 606px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 21px 163px 0 179px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  font-family: SofiaPro;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.16;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.layer-24 {
  background-image: url(Layer 24.png);
  width: 1017px;
  height: 485px;
  margin: 0 142px 40px 141px;
  padding: 139px 1px 185px 0;
}
.text {
  border-top: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  width: 77%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  width: 77%;
  width: 905px;
  height: 94px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.57;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #494848;
}
.lorem {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #82699d;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.leftimg {
  margin: 31px 36px 55px 164px;
  padding: 17px 20px 23px 19px;
}

.righttxt h2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 166px 27px 0px;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.16;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #505051;
}
.righttxt p {
  width: 622px;
  height: 182px;
  margin: 27px 7px 15px 0px;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.87;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #838383;
}
.clients-txt {
  width: 319px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 0px 7px 44px 140px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.57;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}
.client_logos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

------------------


.footer-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.block-right{
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 82px 22px 16px 1000px;
}

.block-left{
  width: 240px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 90px 86px 24px 140px;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 2.4;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #454242;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="line-second"></div>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-nav">
                <a href="#" class="header-nav"> <img src="Home.png" alt=""> Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="header-nav"> <img src="AboutUs.png" alt=""> About Us</a>
                <a href="#" class="header-nav"> <img src="Services.png" alt=""> Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="header-nav"> <img src="ContactUs.png" alt=""> Contact Us</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
            <div class="banner">
                <img src="banner.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <p class='text'><b class='lorem'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>,
                consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <div class="inf">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img class ="leftimg" src="circle.png" alt="" width="310" height="311"></td>
                        <td class="righttxt">
                            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error
                                sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam
                                rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
                                et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                                Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit
                                aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem
                                sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor
                                sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
                                tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="clients">
                    <p class="clients-txt"><b>Where</b> We Have Been Featured</p>
                    <img class="client_logos" src="client_logos.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-container">
            <div class="block-left">
                <p>© Copyright 2010 - All rights reserved</p>
            </div>

            <div class="block-right">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="tweeter" src="tweeter.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="facebook"src="facebook.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Классу `Footer-container` задайте свойство `justify-content: space-between;` (вместо `space-around`) И уберите у класса `block-right` такой большой `margin` отступ слева 1000px.

Это если вы хотели поместить иконки соц. сетей справа в футере (Если я верно понял ваш вопрос).